# If Bluetooth Then Hotspot

Tags: bluetooth, wifi-hotspot, google-pixel-2, ifttt

I have a Pixel 2 and I just installed a Android head unit in my car. I am looking for an app or script that when I get into my car and my Pixel connects by bluetooth to my head unit it turns my Hotspot on so my head unit can get internet connection. I tried IFTTT but that doesn't have an option for it. I am new to Android a bit but pretty computer savvy. Has anyone seen an IFTTT like this or know of how this can be done?

Comment: I am looking into something similar. So far IFTTT does not appear to have any hotspot applets. Various threads talk about an app called TASKER. Not tried it yet. 1 week for free, then one time purchase of about $5.

Comment: @JeffEckstein I saw that too but for it to work on my Pixel with Android 10 I have to root it which is not easy with Android 10 and add TASKER as a system level app and then build the task. TASKER is hard as hell to learn and I have been working on it for 9 months and still haven't figured it out.